# How to upload image from gallery in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to upload image from my phone gallery into my application .In my application there is button named upload. when i click button,it should move to gallery and in gallery if i select image that selected image should display as thumbnail in application.I want to upload 10 images, from gallery in my application.

Answer (score 28):

On click of the gallery button, start startActivityForResult as follows:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), GET_FROM_GALLERY);
```

Consequently, detect GET_FROM_GALLERY (which is a static int, any request number of your choice e.g., `public static final int GET_FROM_GALLERY = 3;`) inside onActivityResult.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    //Detects request codes
    if(requestCode==GET_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here we can upload only one image but i want to upload  10 images simultaneously.now again when i click upload button it should go to gallery and display image beside the previously displaying preview image

Comment: Hey Dhruv how do you display a thumbnail of it?

Comment: This has worked like a charm. I don't know why questioner didn't choose yet.

Comment: `startActivityForResult` is deprecated. There is an alternative way of achieving this [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-select-an-image-from-gallery-in-android/) (scroll below). Works like a charm

Answer (score 8):

To view gallery:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setType("image/*");
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),REQUEST_CODE);
```

and to use it in your app:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  try {
   switch (requestCode) {

   case REQUEST_CODE:
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
     //data gives you the image uri. Try to convert that to bitmap
     break;
    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
     Log.e(TAG, "Selecting picture cancelled");
    }
    break;
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e(TAG, "Exception in onActivityResult : " + e.getMessage());
  }
 }
```

Comment: I treid this code but i need to upload multiple images simultaneously.Also, i need to get thumbnail preview of images simultaneously.

Answer (score 5):

This is the way to go:

```
startActivityForResult(
  new Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
  ),
  GET_FROM_GALLERY
);
```