# upload image from gallery on android studio

Tags: android, gallery

i am trying to upload image from gallery and display it on image view but i am getting this error

```
I/System.out: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: content://media/external/images/media/35
```

my code:

```
 public void btimage(View view)
    {

        Intent i = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(i, 100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==100 && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri uri= data.getData();
            imgView.setImageURI(uri);

        }
    }
```

Comment: need more code than that but it seems that you send the wrong location in `uri` that came from your parameter `data`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload image from gallery in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107900/how-to-upload-image-from-gallery-in-android)

Comment: you want to upload image are, want to display on Imageview from gallery?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```

for

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```